# How long to turn a valley into a village?

Tags: geography, survival

So a group of villagers go up a very high mountain range fleeing from raiders. The urgency of their flight forces them to face the harsh mountains and, in their desperation, they end up finding a narrow and perilous trail going down to a small hidden valley where they can lay low for a while.

My question is: Given enough time and assuming that the valley has enough wildlife, fertile lands and a good river running through it, how long would a group of *x* people take, working *every hour of every day*, to create a self-sufficient village in the valley?

I am interested in a village with either medieval or late antiquity levels of technology. Either one is fine by me.

The village need not be fancy but it needs to be comfortable and allow for the entire population to survive and thrive in the cold mountain climate (assume tall Chinese mountains) year-round.

I am also interested in the smallest **x** amount of people that would make such an endeavor possible.

Comment: "self-sufficient village" - how do you define a self-sufficient village, at what tech level? History is rich with examples just like you described - only such villages, in industrial age, are not very advanced.

Comment: Look up [Roman military camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_military_camp) (castra).  To quote, "as soon as they have marched into an enemy's land, they do not begin to fight until they have walled their camp about; nor is the fence they raise rashly made, or uneven; nor do they all abide ill it, ... but if it happens that the ground is uneven, it is first levelled: their camp is also four-square by measure, and carpenters are ready, in great numbers, with their tools, to erect their buildings for them."  Now it's just a question of villager talent and economic limitations.

Comment: @Alexander I have amended my question to specify tech level.

Comment: Please define "Self-sufficient village" if there's sufficient food to forage, then just by being there and foraging, they're self sufficient. But is that a village? Please clarify what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not possible - but stretching definitions...**

A group of people could create a self-sufficient *stone age* village in a single valley, but a medieval / late antiquity level of technology cannot be sustained by such a small group.  It is not possible to have an Iron Age without iron (and copper and other metals) and any village is too small to run a mine and a smelting operation (which involves massive amounts of tree felling for charcoal creation) *and* grow / hunt their own food.  Not to mention rope making, cartwrights and other specialised professions that would not typically be found in every village.  Just as it is estimated to take a minimum of hundreds of millions to a few billion humans to maintain today's technology level, the minimum population for a fully functioning medieval society would be in the thousands at least just to maintain key parts of the tech tree.

**Building materials**

If the villagers somehow had with them all the tools that they require *and* stocks of iron *and* wheeled carts pulled by horses or oxen (hard to move the iron and tools otherwise) then one timeliness problem is in getting seasoned timber to build with - building with green timber will not result in good high-quality structures.  This will require felling the timber, splitting and sawing it into beams and planks and then storing it somewhere sheltered but well-ventilated - which means building temporary structures with green timber to shelter the seasoning timber.  Depending on various conditions, seasoning the timber will take from 3-12 months - in a cold mountain valley in China it's likely to be towards the upper end of that range.

So there's the first limit - after a good site for the village has been determined and woodcutting commenced, it will be a minimum of a year after there is enough leisure to build temporary shelters for seasoning wood before the first permanent building can start to be raised.  In the meantime the would-be villagers need to be foraging and hunting for food, building temporary shelters for themselves and their livestock, cutting thatching and setting it to dry for every building that is going to be constructed in the next year, clearing fields for crops, finding clay and baking it into bricks, using some of the bricks to create a forge to allow the manufacture and repair of tools, nails, plough blades etc...

**Building the tools to make the tools...**

Note that if the settlers do not have good quality axes, saws, adzes etc *and* the tools to maintain them then the priorities need to get rearranged and another few months at least need to be added to the timeframe - before any of the timber felling can commence they need to get the clay (using poor quality wooden spades) and make the bricks to make the forge *and* get wood and turn the wood into charcoal so their blacksmith (they do have a blacksmith? with all his tools?) can turn the stock iron into the axes, saws, adzes needed for the timber felling *plus* the drills, hammers and so on that will be required for subsequent construction.

Do they have ropes and chains for handling heavy logs?  Chain can't be made until the blacksmith is up and running, and each chain will require a significant amount of the precious, irreplaceable iron.  Rope making is extremely tedious and requires the right sort of fibres to be available, but is invaluable for transport and construction.

**Food and clothing**

Crops need to be established before the valley's natural resources are exhausted.  Hopefully the settlers arrived in early spring and brought their own seed grain with them, that way they have a chance of clearing a few fields and having a chance of harvesting a crop in autumn that will let them survive the winter.  They really want established, cultivated grains that humans have been selectively breeding for thousands of years, as native varieties are far less productive.  In the meantime they will need to balance foraging, hunting and fishing with their "village building" activities in order to remain fed.  Ideally they are also balancing goat herding with those other activities - if they are not going to be entirely fur-wearing then they need some fabric fibres and goats are probably the most durable species of domesticated animal they could bring with them.  The alternative to goats or sheep is to be growing not just food crops but also something like flax or cotton *and* to be relying entirely on hunting and fishing for animal protein.

**How many people?**  You need enough strong able-bodied adults to be able to fell trees, handle large timber beams during construction, pull large rocks out of fields so they can be ploughed and conduct a multitude of other tasks.  Key skills include woodworking, timber construction, wheelwright, kiln construction and operation, charcoal burning, farming, herding and animal husbandry, shearing, hunting, wilderness survival.  There also needs to be enough genetic diversity that at least the children and preferably the grandchildren of the original settlers can avoid inbreeding.  Eight people - four couples - is probably the minimum to provide the numbers, skill sets and genetic diversity to survive.

How long would it take?  Let's say that the first year is used clearing fields and using any wood from these for firewood and building the temporary shelters and animal enclosures needed, planting a crop and subsequent harvesting, finding clay and making bricks, while foraging and hunting from this Garden of Eden-like setting to remain fed.  Towards the end of the year the blacksmith's forge can be built.  In the second year timber can be felled, shaped and started seasoning, in the autumn thatch can be gathered and dried and the fields can be expanded.  In the third year the initial permanent dwellings can be built and the village can be considered to be "established".

This timeline requires an almost impossibly ideal set of conditions:

- The settlers arrive with ample hand tools, a full set of blacksmith's tools, at least one cart and beast of burden to pull it, sufficient stock iron to build all other tools required, seed grain of all required types in sufficient quantity, rope, chain, tents, sustainable herd of goats.
- None of the settlers is injured, unwell or disabled for any significant period of time during the construction.
- The settlers have all the skills required to undertake all tasks required in perfect safety.
- The valley's fish, wildlife and edible plants are not exhausted before the settlers have reached the stage of growing sufficient food.
- There is timber and clay accessible and appropriate for construction.

Failure of any one of these conditions will either increase the timeline significantly or make the settlers simply stone age rather than arguably late ancient / medieval.

**Self-sufficient?**  The village can survive given reasonable future conditions, but if it remains isolated it will almost certainly regress technologically.  Iron tools will rust away and cannot be replaced without more metal.  There are probably enough goats to continue with some inbreeding, but once the horse or oxen has aged too much then ploughing and other tasks will rely on human muscles alone.  At this point even the use of the wheel may be reduced.  Inbreeding will eventually take its toll on the human population.

In summary - 8 able-bodied adults could probably establish a "village" ("hamlet"?) over a period of 3 years given an ideal combination of initial resources and conditions.  However, the long-term sustainability of the settlement is questionable if it remains isolated.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest amount of people is one.

In a fertile valley one skilled person could build a permanent dwelling in the time it took their first crops to grow. They would need to survive on whatever hunting fishing and gathering was available until then.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not sustainable past this one person's lifetime and that lifetime will be shorter. One person attempting to hunt / fish / gather in old age doesn't live as long. The person is also more susceptible to depression.

Comment: @DavidR strange that old hermits abound in stories. But I don't think you understood the answer, I'm not suggesting they hunter gather forever

Answer (score 1):

I'll second @Kilisi answer - the smallest number is one, but I'd like to offer a second opinion as well.

Of course a village of one can exist, but it also can fail very easily. A bad fall from a steep trail can end life of our hermit together with this village. And probably we can call only a settlement that can proliferate on its own "a village". With this definition, we'll need **at least 4 people** - two fertile couples to start this villages. Potentially, we can start with just one couple - but that would require second generation of villagers to intermarry, which is not good for health of their descendants. Ideally, we'll need thousands to avoid genetic deceases, but 4 in most cases would suffice for a number of generations.